# According to deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit, are there any other examples of spirits devoid of sentience in the Bible?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology, spirit

According to deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit, is it possible to make an inductive case against the personhood of the Holy Spirit by appealing to other examples of spirits without personhood in the Bible? Can we find other examples of spiritual beings in the Bible that lack sentience? Or is the Holy Spirit *one-of-a-kind* in this regard?

Comment: Can the Holy Spirit be said to be a "spirit being" according to deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit?

Comment: Those who are deniers of the Personhood of the Holy Spirit believe that the words _agios pneuma_ refer to the 'spirit' of a single divine entity. They do not accept that the words apply to a 'spiritual being'. You are asking for examples of 'other spiritual beings'. I cannot see how this question will work.

Comment: Good points, but in that case the answer would be that the Holy Spirit is *one-of-a-kind*, correct?

Comment: The 'deniers' might well say that the 'spirit of God' is unique, yes. But you say 'one' - 'of a kind'. One what ? Again you suggest 'being' or 'person' by 'one'. And I suggest that it still doesn't work (in my own view). They would say 'a unique attribute' (perhaps).

Comment: @NigelJ - the Holy Spirit would be *one-of-a-kind* in the sense that it is the only example of a  kind of spirits which are unconscious, whereas all other spirits that we know of (angels, demons, etc.) are conscious.

Comment: Spirits do not have bodies and do not suffer death. How can they _ever_ be 'unconscious' ? ? ? I repeat, some think that the 'spirit of God' refers to an _attribute_ of God. Like a mind or a faculty.

Comment: @NigelJ - perhaps my question is flawed, or can only be answered in the negative, but that's fine, hopefully answerers will make that clear in their answers.

Comment: 1) who are these deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit?  2) how can a spirit being not be sentient?  Can you provide examples of both?  I think you need to be aware of two very different categories here: for 1) the underlying being is indescribable (God) so language about person and spirit is analogical and we are at the mercy of how God discloses himself to us as 3 persons in spirit, but in 2) the underlying being is a creature and all created spirits (angel/demon and humans) are sentient and as spirit beings ourselves we can in theory perceive them directly spirit to spirit.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple You ask, "who are these deniers?"  Jehovah's Witnesses, Christian Science, Christadelphians, Oneness Pentecostals,  the Unification Church, and Unitarianism who are Arians like the Jw's and view the Holy Spirit as the power of God the Father.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Oh I see.  I'm not familiar with their theology.  Regardless, I think this question is misguided.  How can you generalize from God's being to created being?  I would think even a member of those denominations recognize the unbridgeable gulf between God and created being, and thus recognize that our language of God is necessarily analogical, not real.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Well you should be familiar with these groups, how can you not since you've been here with over 14,000 post. These groups are talked about all the time. Now, please explain what you mean when you say, "How can you generalize from God's being to created being?" Are you saying the Holy Spirit is created and so is the Son? Just asking for clarity.

Comment: @Mr.Bond the The OP asks whether it's possible to make an "inductive case", which means the OP wants to generalize from created spirit to the being of God.  I'm saying that such procedure is fundamentally a [category mistake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake).  About those groups, I'm glad you know more about them, adding diversity to our community.  Yes, I would rather deepen my focus among Trinitarian Christians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The only word translated as "spirit" in Hebrew is רוּחַ, pronounced ruach. It has many meanings; it does not only refer to an "immaterial sentient entity", e.g. God(John 4:24), angels(Hebrews 1:14), demons(Luke 4:33), etc. Thus, the "Holy Spirit" is **not** necessarily a conscious spirit entity.

Let's see some places where רוּחַ does **NOT** refer to a *conscious spirit being*.

- Genesis 3:8 And they heard the sound of the Lord God walking in the garden in the **cool**[רוּחַ] of the day, and the man and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the  Lord God among the trees of the garden.
- Genesis 6:17 For behold, I will bring a flood of waters upon the earth to destroy all flesh in which is the **breath**[רוּחַ] of life under heaven. Everything that is on the earth shall die.
- Genesis 7:15 They went into the ark with Noah, two and two of all flesh in which there was the **breath**[רוּחַ] of life.
- Genesis 7:22 They went into the ark with Noah, two and two of all flesh in which there was the **breath**[רוּחַ] of life.
- Genesis 8:1 But God remembered Noah and all the beasts and all the livestock that were with him in the ark. And God made a **wind**[רוּחַ] blow over the earth, and the waters subsided.
- Exodus 10:19 And the  Lord turned the wind into a very strong west **wind**[רוּחַ], which lifted the locusts and drove them into the Red Sea. Not a single locust was left in all the country of Egypt.
- Exodus 15:8 At the **blast**[רוּחַ] of your nostrils the waters piled up; the floods stood up in a heap; the deeps congealed in the heart of the sea.
- Numbers 5:14 and if the **spirit**[רוּחַ] of jealousy comes over him and he is jealous of his wife who has defiled herself, or if the spirit of jealousy comes over him and he is jealous of his wife, though she has not defiled herself,
- 2 Chronicles 9:4 the food of his table, the seating of his officials, and the attendance of his servants, and their clothing, his cupbearers, and their clothing, and his burnt offerings that he offered at the house of the  Lord, there was no more **breath**[רוּחַ] in her.
- 2 Chronicles 21:16 And the  Lord stirred up against Jehoram the **anger**[רוּחַ] of the Philistines and of the Arabians who are near the Ethiopians.
- Job 7:7 “Remember that my life is a **breath**[רוּחַ]; my eye will never again see good.
- Job 41:16 One is so near to another that no **air**[רוּחַ] can come between them.
- Psalm 33:6 By the word of the  Lord the heavens were made, and by the **breath**[רוּחַ] of His mouth all their host.
- Proverbs 16:32 He who is slow to anger is better than a warrior, and he who controls his **temper**[רוּחַ] is greater than one who captures a city.
- Proverbs 25:28 A man without **self-control**[רוּחַ] is like a city broken into and left without walls.
- Isaiah 33:11 You conceive chaff; you give birth to stubble; your **breath**[רוּחַ] is a fire that will consume you.
- Jeremiah 14:6 The wild donkeys stand on the bare heights; they pant for **air**[רוּחַ] like jackals; their eyes fail because there is no vegetation.

Hope this helps! Have a good day. :)

Comment: Insightful OT references (+1). What about NT references? For example, Acts 1:8 refers to the Holy Spirit as Ἁγίου Πνεύματος. Are there examples of "Πνεύματος beings" lacking sentience in the NT?

Comment: Where did the "beings" come from? I'm not the one adding "being" to it. Nowhere is the Holy Spirit(whether OT or NT) called a "spirit being", but only a "spirit"; as I've shown, "spirit" does not only refer to "spirit being"(though it can). You should ask if there are any examples of "πνεύμα" lacking sentience; yes, there are. Thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: Oh, I see, you are questioning the presupposition that the Holy Spirit must be a being. It could be seen instead as some sort of impersonal "divine energy" or "divine power", as Jehovah's Witnesses and Biblical Unitarians understand it. Then let me phrase the question again without the "being" bias: are there examples of "Πνεύματος" without sentience in the NT?

Comment: I don't classify the Holy Spirit as a "divine power", because to classify something suggests you know what it is; I do not know what the Holy Spirit is, and I don't think anyone CAN know what the Holy Spirit is. If I could put it in analogy(to the best of my abilities), I would say the Holy Spirit is God's DNA that He's capable of extending and imprinting on His creation. Now, do you understand the Holy Spirit? I hope not, cause neither do I!